# What is the cardinality of the set of all roots of natural numbers?

Tags: elementary-set-theory

I'm very new to this kind of stuff; I'd greatly appreciate some feedback.

---

Let $\mathcal{S}$ denote the set of all natural roots. Since $\mathcal{S}$ is a subset of the algebraic numbers, we know it is countable; $|\mathcal{S}| \leq |\mathbb{N}| = \aleph_0$. We can construct an injection $g: \mathbb{N} \rightarrow \mathcal{S}$ by sending each natural number to its square root. Hence, $|\mathcal{S}| \geq |\mathbb{N}| = \aleph_0$. By the Schroder-Bernstein Theorem, $|\mathcal{S}| = \aleph_0$.

---

My other idea was to show that it is a countable union of countable sets, which would replace the first half of the proof (that it is a subset of the algebraic numbers).

Comment: Both proofs seem correct to me.

Comment: Both proofs are correct.  The second is the clearest and foolproof but it requires knowing the algebraic numbers are countable.  The first is basically a simplified proof of the algebraic number proof.

Answer (score 1):

As @MohammadRiazi-Kermani already noted, your method is fine. I'll comment briefly on the alternative you considered, of showing the set cannot be uncountable because it's a subset of $\Bbb A$. Note the proof that *that* is countable uses basically the same strategy as your first proof: we count the polynomials with multiplicity, viz. $\sum_{k=0}^\infty(k+1)\aleph_0^k=\sum_k\aleph_0=\aleph_0$.

Answer (score 0):

Once you have shown the set is countable you can conclude that it has the same  cardinality as  natural numbers because your set is infinite.

I like your second approach better because it sounds more elegant.

Comment: Thank you. Must I first show that it isn't finite, though? That's why I constructed an injection from $\mathbb{N}$ to $\mathcal{S}$. I know it's trivial, but I can never be too sure what I can leave out.

Comment: You are correct. You try to make sure that everything is explained thoroughly.